# A little help with CSS on my WordPress website!

Tags: php, css, wordpress, alignment

I recently made a website using WordPress and a custom theme. There is one weird glitch that's been bothering me, and due to my limited CSS knowledge I've been scratching my head.

If you go to the home page http://wpwallpaper.com/, you can see that on the right side there is a sidebar with categories (Abstract Bright, Dark, Sexy) and an "Advertise Here" block. It's displaying correctly. However, if you click on one of the images on the front page, say, this one: http://wpwallpaper.com/dark/bluedroid/ You will notice that the right side bar is gone...instead it's wrapped around and appearing at the bottom of the page!

I've been using the Chrome developer tool to mess around with the CSS but to no avail. I basically want the sidebar to go back to the right side instead of at the bottom.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Ya, I've been using the Inspect Element tool in Chrome.  It's awesome :)

Comment: btw html is still invalid..
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwpwallpaper.com%2Fdark%2Fbluedroid%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0
trust me fixing errors listed there is really helpful :D

Answer (score 2):

This div `<div class="wrapper" id='wrapper_main'>` has no closing tag `</div>`
Add it and all will be corrected

The missing `</div>` should be added before

```
<div class="wrapper fullwidth" id='wrapper_footer'>
```

Comment: I copied the source code from Chrome into Visual Studio which told me there was a missing `</div>`

Comment: Na, it's there.  Maybe it was expanded and you didn't select it somehow.  Thanks for trying though!

Comment: @Carlos: That isn't it. I ran the page through the w3c validator and it didn't complain about missing a closing `</div>` tag, though there were a couple other minor issues.

Comment: Then Chrome has lied to me! I am sorry if it's not correct. I'll check again in firefox

Comment: Well It is fixed now. I don't have the previous code. Now I'll never know if it was what I said or not.

Comment: @Carlos: It might not have been your fault. I think I got here after he fixed it... I ran it through the validator before I visually inspected the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check  or missing HTML tags(closing)

And check div for height and fix the width of left and right div

Answer (score 0):

There were some incorrect code in my single.php file in the theme...I commented out the code and all was working well!

Comment: Incorrect code that generated the wrong divs. Remember that I wass talking about divs from the HTMl source code not from php's spource code